# Switch to another app's active window only

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

Command+Tab and Command+Shift+Tab - toggles between apps

Command+` and Command+Shift+` - toggles between windows of the currently active app

Is there a way to switch to another app but only to the most recently active window (so that it doesn't dredge up the rest of the app's windows)?

I have multiple windows open for some apps and having this would be very handy especially if I have one has limited screen space.

If not available, is there a way to create such a shortcut through System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts for all applications?

Thanks!

Comment: did you look at this ? http://manytricks.com/witch/

Comment: No, thanks for showing it to me. I'll give it a test drive. Do you have any experience with using it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seem to be two proprietary programs that do solve this problem, but there isn't a way to set it up yourself using a keyboard shortcut.

The two apps are Witch (as suggested by Buscar웃) and Contexts, in case someone wanted to check them both out. Witch costs $14, and Contexts costs $9.

I'm trying both to see which one fits my needs most as both offer a free trial.

http://manytricks.com/witch/

https://contexts.co